# ASP.NET membership roles - event management

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm working on a project for an events site. I want to create it so that users can create an event and they become the admin for only that event, and they can authorise others as fellow admins (FB style), meanwhile they are only a user for. Is it possible to use the existing roles tools built into .NET to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create your own table for it. [eventId, userId]

Comment: You could do it by creating roles on the fly and making everyone able to administer some of the roles, but you'll likely wind up fighting the system. Better to do as Hatsjoem suggested and save the owner of each event with the event and using another table to grant access to the events for additional users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments provided are pretty useful (create your own table for it\creating roles on the fly).  In short, the functionality you are looking for is not currently available in the existing Universal Role Provider packaged with .NET.  However, the URP is intended to only be a starting framework for you to work with\edit as you see fit.  I would use a combination of these 2 suggestions, using the built in role provider tables to generate roles on the fly, and use a custom table to manage that hierarchy.

Hope this helps, and welcome to Stack Overflow!